# Terraform interpolation throwing error when using terraform.workspace option

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

so I am trying to do interpolation i-e with **`public scheme`** and **`terraform.workspace`** so subnets will dynamically get selected. For that tried merging `terraform.workspace` with `elb_subnets` but its throwing error that ***only supported key for 'terraform.X' interpolations is 'workspace'***

```
variable "elb_scheme" {
  default = "public"
}

variable "prod_elb_subnets" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    public  = "subnet-23ywe324, subnet-234hj34, subnet-cdh7868"
    private = "subnet-hj3h2323, subnet-jihi782, subnet-237dew"
  }
}

variable "qa_elb_subnets" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    public  = "subnet-234ee234, subnet-da238sdf, subnet-sd2233"
    private = "subnet-09jsdf23, subnet-hi232rf, subnet-89832w32"
  }
}

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBSubnets"

    value = "${var.(terraform.workspace_elb_subnets["${var.elb_scheme}"])}"
  }
```

**output:**

```
Error: module.ebs.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.ebs.aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.beanstalk: terraform.workspace_elb_subnets: only supported key for 'terraform.X' interpolations is 'workspace'
```

**Terraform workspace**

```
terraform workspace list
  default
* qa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using a nested map, and using `terraform.workspace` as the key. Like so

```
variable "elb_scheme" {
  default = "public"
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    prod = {
      public  = "subnet-23ywe324, subnet-234hj34, subnet-cdh7868"
      private = "subnet-hj3h2323, subnet-jihi782, subnet-237dew"
    }

    qa = {
      public  = "subnet-234ee234, subnet-da238sdf, subnet-sd2233"
      private = "subnet-09jsdf23, subnet-hi232rf, subnet-89832w32"
    }
  }
}

output "my_subnets" {
  value = "${lookup(var.subnets[terraform.workspace],"${var.elb_scheme}")}"
}
```

Comment: How do I lookup as list itself and not as comma separated string